# segfault at 10 when use python-ESL module to develop freeswitch application

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, debian, swig, freeswitch

I am developting a freeswith application, when I used python ESL module, I always got the error: segfault at 10 ip 00007fdcec6e39ba sp 00007fdcd4e1d4c0 error 4 in _ESL.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so[7fdcec6de000+12000], why? I installed the ESL module by "pip install python-ESL" in version 1.4.18, and my freeswitch version is 1.10.10. Is there any laster python ESL version?
My OS is debian, the swig version is 3.0.60.

who can resove this problem and maybe provide me a newer version python esl module?